# Can't get data from HTTP GET request Nodejs and Angular2

Tags: http, angular2-routing, nodes, mean-stack

I'm trying to get data from my local database.
local url: **http://localhost:8000/**

I call this in my service **/getPersonalInfoData**
status showing 200, but I can't see any data there.

component.ts:

```
var data = this.personalInfoService.getPersonalInfoData()
            .subscribe(arg => this.driverData = arg);
            console.log(data);
```

personalInfoService:

```
return this.http.get('/getPersonalInfoData').map((res: Response) => { console.log(res); return res; });
```

backend data source API(Nodejs):

```
routes.get('/getPersonalInfoData',personal_info_controller.getPersonalInfoData);
```

Comment: have you tested your api using postman ?

Comment: ya,...its working fine

Answer (score 1):

In personalInfoService:-

1.import `{  Http,  Response,  Headers,  RequestOptions, URLSearchParams}` from`'@angular/http'`;

2.In method add this code:

```
const headers = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-control': 'no-cache',
      Expires: '0',
      Pragma: 'no-cache'
    });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get(Url, options).map(res => {
      return res.json();
    });
```

Hope this will help you.